# Security component for Yii framework compulsory?

Tags: php, security, yii

If an existing non-framework using project decides to incorporate Yii, would it be possible to continue using the old non-framework security mechanism? Or would using Yii also necessitate the Yii security module/mechanism?

Comment: What is this security mechanism? Login form? Custom CSRF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody forces you to use all the features provided by Yii. It's up to you. You can create your own component in Yii and continue using your own security module/mechanism.